# need systemd error loging document

Tags: c, logging, syslog, rsyslog, systemd

With syslog error logging beign expired in some Linux distributions like arch Linux, I am looking for some way to log error with systemd but I couldn't find any documentation or resource about it. If you know about error logging with systemd please help me.

Comment: _Google_ is not a bad place to look.  Try something like _Replacement for systemd error log new versions of Linux_

Answer (score 1):

If you need to log something from your application just print to stderr in a way like:

`#include <systemd/sd-daemon.h>`

`// some code here`

`fprintf(stderr, SD_ERR "Some error meassge from the app");`

`// some code there`

If you want to the message type at the command prompt:

`$ systemd-journalctl`

See [this](http://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/journalctl.html) and [that](http://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/sd-journal.html) and [that](http://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/sd-daemon.html).